# Can't add OAuth 2.0 scopes LinkedIn

Tags: java, oauth, linkedin-api

I don't have the ability to change OAuth scope in the Linkedin developers page.
That's why while trying to get an authorization code I get this error:

```
error=unauthorized_scope_error&error_description=Scope+%26quot%3Br_basicprofile%26quot%3B+is+not+authorized+for+your+application
```

[image]

You can see the OAuth scopes section in my profile. I just can't set up any scopes.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Navigate to **Products** in the LinkedIn Developer Console and select **Sign in with LinkedIn**.

The verification process takes a few moments and then `r_emailaddress` and
`r_liteprofile` should appear under your permissions.

Comment: Provide visual examples and explanation of what `r_emailaddress` and `r_liteprofile` are.  "Navigate to X" is not always obvious.

Comment: I just tried this with a test app and LinkedIn is saying "your request is being reviewed by the LinkedIn platform team. It takes 3-5 working days to review an application." – not very convenient for getting started.

Answer (score 6):

I want to give a few more details to the answer given by @asood711

Navigate to **Products** in the LinkedIn Developer Console of the app and select **Sign in with LinkedIn**.

[image]

The verification process takes a few moments and then **r_emailaddress** and **r_liteprofile** should appear under your permissions.

Comment: More details here https://docs.pathfix.com/integrating-with-linkedin

Answer (score 2):

This link provides steps for you to be able to do that.

https://docs.pathfix.com/integrating-with-linkedin.

But I think you need to get the owner of the company profile to verify your app before you can do this. If done then you should be good to go.

The scopes are added through adding of products. That is the third tab on the linked screen.

Hope this helps :)